# Where do g++, make and GDB get installed with MinGW?

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, mingw, eclipse-cdt

**Please note:** Although I'm specifically talking about the Eclipse CDT plugin, I'm almost 100% confident that any Windows/C/MinGW programmer can answer this question.

I'm on Windows 7 and am trying to write and compile a simple "Hello, C!" C application using Eclipse's CDT plugin. I'm reading their [docs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/) which state that having GCC installed is a prerequisite.

I just installed MinGW, making sure to include the following packages:

- `mingw-developer-toolkit`
- `mingw32-base`
- `mingw32-gcc-g++`
- `msys-base`

Back in the CDT docs (under the section titled **Windows configuration**), it states that I need to add `g++`, `make` and `GDB` to my PATH.

**I'm wondering where MinGW installs these utilities, so that I can add them to my system PATH, and make the Eclipse CDT recognize their location at startup.**

Comment: In a directory I think, search for them.

Comment: Thanks @iharob (+1) but that could take **half a day** with the size of my hard drive, and also doesn't serve any use to future newcomers to this site who might be wondering the same thing.

Comment: How did you install those MinGW packages? I'm sure you answered where to install during setup...

Comment: Thanks @Diego (+1) - I was never prompted at any time for such an install location. I downloaded the **MinGW Installation Manager**, which simply presented me with all the packages I *could* install, I selected them (see the list above) and it installed them for me, automagically.

Comment: I think if you know how the windows filesystem is organized you can search for it quickly, and are you serious **half a day**? What kind of computer you have? is is windows OS so slow? In my OS I just type `find /usr -name make` and about 10 seconds there it will be `/usr/bin/make`, and it's not a ultra fast computer, just a regular amd cpu.

Comment: I think the default is C:\MinGW, I'm not sure, look in their docs :)

Comment: Thanks again @Diego (+1) - you got me 67% of the way there, as `g++` and `gdb` are in fact now installed under `C:\MinGW\bin`. However in order for Eclipse CDT to work correctly, it also needs to know where `make` is installed, and I'm not seeing it anywhere under that `bin` dir. Am I looking in the wrong place? Do I need to install an additional MinGW package to gain access to `make`? Thanks again!

Comment: OK @Diego, it took a bit more of time, but I found `make` under `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`. Now all you have to do is convert your comments into a simple answer explaining what MinGW packages need to be installed, and where these 3 utilities get installed to, and I will happily upvote you and give you the green check!

Comment: Make is in MinGW\msys\1.0\bin.

Comment: I beat you to it, but thanks anyways @Jonas (+1) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Eclipse CDT plugin, you need GCC and its 3 specific utilities installed locally. These three utilities are: `g++`, `make` and `gdb`.

On Windows you can choose to install these utilities via Cygwin or MinGW. For a MinGW-based solution, go to their site and download the **MinGW Package Manager**. Then open the manager and install the following packages:

- `mingw-developer-toolkit`
- `mingw32-base`
- `mingw32-gcc-g++`
- `msys-base`

Then go to `File >> Apply Updates` and apply them. This will install the 3 utilities to the following directories on your machine:

- `C:\MinGW\bin\g++`
- `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb`
- `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\make`

Add these 3 binaries to your system `PATH`, restart Eclipse and you are all set.